# There is no driver for my phone's model number

Tags: samsung-galaxy-j7

I use a Samsung J7 mobile phone, model number SM-J700F (checked both below the battery and in the "about phone" section). I live in Israel, so I don't use one of the four big main carriers.

I tried inputting my model number in the Samsung website
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/ but right as I enter the last character in my model number ("F") i get "please enter a valid model number.

What do to?

Comment: A driver for what?

Comment: OEM driver for my phone. I need it for android USB debugging.

Comment: The F variant is not sold in the US, hence what you get. The generic one [supplied by Samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows) should work alright.

Answer (score 1):

[ADB Minimal](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790) should come with those drivers, and you might need the [Samsung USB Drivers](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows) and lastly there is Smart Switch. I don't know about it much but it should provide drivers just like Kies did, although the first two should work real fine. Good luck!